# Where is the Datum stored in PAB?

Tags: utxo, pab, datum

In utxo we store only the hash of the datum, so whenever you work with the Cardano cli to run a transaction - you should provide datum or its hash via tx-out-datum-embed-file, tx-in-datum-file, etc.

What about the PAB?

Did I understand correctly that original datum is stored in chainindex?
At what step is original Datum sent from PAB to the chainindex?

If the datum is stored in chaindex - does it mean that all PAB apps should be connected to the same chainindex in order to share datum with each other?
Are we going to have a global chainindex available for all PABs?
What if two PABs are connected to different chainindex servers, does it mean that the datum will not be shared between them?

Answer (score 1):

Datum and redeemer (all required data for script execution) are stored on-chain as well so the node can optionally verify the script execution outcome when replaying the chain.

Since chainindex follows a chain using connection to `cardano-node` it receives all the executed scripts, datums and redeemers after they get committed on-chain.

Which means that even different chain-index servers will see the same script data.